# Weird time response results for simple load test with gatling

Tags: gatling

I would like to execute load tests on my server with Gatling 2.0.0-M3 on my mac (Mac OS 10.8.1).

I have two REST services to test: version and health-check. These services does not connect to any database and are relatively simple. They returns in the body some text. When I try to load test one service a time, response time seems correct (less than 10 ms).
However, when I mix the call to these services, response time is above 12,000 ms.

That's the code I wrote to test my services:

```
class MonitoringServices extends Simulation {
    val httpProtocol = http.baseURL("http://10.12.84.19:5000")
                           .acceptHeader("text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8")
                           .acceptEncodingHeader("gzip, deflate")
                           .acceptLanguageHeader("fr,fr-fr;q=0.8,en-us;q=0.5,en;q=0.3")
                           .connection("keep-alive")
                           .userAgentHeader("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:24.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/24.0")

    val headers_1 = Map(
                        "Accept" -> "application/json;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
                        "Accept-Charset" -> "ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.7",
                        "Cache-Control" -> "max-age=0"
    )
    val scn1 = scenario("Monitoring services: version")
                  .exec(http("version")
                  .get("/mood-engine/v1/version")
                  .headers(headers_1)
                  .check(status.is(200))
               )

    val scn2 = scenario("Monitoring services: health-check")
                   .exec(http("version")
                   .get("/mood-engine/v1/health-check")
                   .headers(headers_1)
                   .check(status.is(200))
               )

    setUp(
        scn1.inject(
            atOnce(1 user),
            constantRate(1 usersPerSec) during (10 seconds)
        ),
        scn2.inject(
            atOnce(1 user),
            constantRate(1 usersPerSec) during (10 seconds)
        )
    ).protocols(httpProtocol)
     .assertions(global.responseTime.max.lessThan(350))
}
```

Do you have any clue?

Answer (score 0):

There's a good chance the problem is in your system under test (dead lock?).
Can you monitor the server side? If it runs on a JVM, you could try VisualVM or YourKit and see what your threads do.

PS: please upgrade to M3a that's a fix we've released shortly after M3.

Comment: Thank for your response, we investigated on our system and it was a wrong configuration of our python server.

Comment: So Gatling served its purpose :)